# %DESKTOPDIR% передать в скрипт PY

Tags: python, windows

Есть в винде переменная `%DESKTOPDIR%` ведет к рабочему столу(у меня рабочий стол на диске `F://Desktop`)

как передать эту переменную в скрипте питона?

```
import os
desktop_file = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop/myfile.txt")
```

Не работает, она ведет на диск C:

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98071/discussion-on-question-by-yurik-gagarin-desktopdir----py).

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте [os.environ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ):

```
import os
dir = os.environ['DESKTOPDIR']
desktop_file = dir + "/myfile.txt"
print(desktop_file)
```

Еще лучше проверять наличие этого переменной, типа:

```
if 'DESKTOPDIR' not in os.environ:
    print('Env "DESKTOPDIR" not exist!')
    quit()
```

Либо через `get` запрашивать, указывая дефолтное значение:

```
dir = os.environ.get('DESKTOPDIR', 'F:/Desktop')
```

---

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал, но там тоже не выдает нужного результата, буду копать дальше

Comment: В os.environ отсутствует параметр DESKTOPDIR

Comment: @YurikGagarin, а у вас оно в системных переменных указано? Добавил скриншот, надеюсь, это поможет :)